# Link excel calculator to online HTML app?

Tags: python, html, css, excel, calculator

I am trying to convert a large excel calculator into an online website for people to freely use.

I have been working on this project for a few months now, and the equations within the excel sheets that are used to derive the answers are too complicated for me to program it from the ground up.

Are there any easy ways to take an excel calculator (workbook with 5 sheets) and turn it into a web app? Any assistance or guidance would be appreciated.

I have also tried opening the document in python using OpenpyXL and manipulating it that way, but it doesn't work.

Web design is totally out of my area of expertise, but I told my employer I would try anyway. Again, I appreciate any assistance.

Comment: There is no magic formula or converter. You just have to adapt and move the concepts over yourself. I don't think anyone on here can give you a reasonable description of what you can do step by step. You'll need to learn some development first and then go from there.

Comment: That's unfortunate. Thanks for the response though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does your work have office 365? You can host the excel file online for everyone to access. It works just like normal excel does but it is througt the online interface. Buttons and everything should work.

Math isn't hard to do with javascript and you can learn super quickly on codeacademy (it's the first thing they teach) and how to display those numbers. Including prompting users for input if you want to go that route.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I will try this and see how it works!

Answer (score 2):

(Disclaimer: I'm the founder of GRID, but the product was created to solve exactly the need described in this question)

GRID provides a WYSIWYG editor for building a web UI on top of existing Excel (or Google Sheets) workbooks to then embed in any web page.

The calculations run client side in a sophisticated spreadsheet engine that can run even fairly complex models lightning-fast, allowing for interactivity such as sliders and inputs to dynamically control outputs such as charts and tables.

This will save you the work of recreating calculations in JavaScript, and updating the calculator in case of a pricing change or other tweaks becomes a simple matter of exchanging the underlying workbook.